# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k^2x^2} =\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Prove that $$\lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2x^2} \right) =\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}.$$

Comment: The OP means $ \arctan (x) $. Notice she wrote $ \tan^{-1}(x) $, not $ \tan(x)^{-1} $.

Comment: @AhaanRungta Yes sorry I recognize that my edit was wrong.

Comment: It would be useful if you could tell us what you have tried. This helps us to understand what you already know so we can better focus our help. Also, people around here get touchy when people just post a question without motivation etc. as they are unwilling to simply do others homework for them, moreover they dislike it when a third party steps in and does the homework for them anyway so questions like this which merely states a question tend to get closed (pending adding more info). Adding in what you have tried and where you came across it will stop your question getting closed in this way.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You may recognize a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^{2}+k^{2}x^{2}} &= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\left( 1+\left( \frac{kx}{n} \right)^{2} \right)}\\ &= \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left( 1+\left( kx \right)^{2} \right)}dk\\ &= \left. \frac{1}{x}\tan^{-1}kx \right|_{k=0}^{k=1}\\ &= \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}\end{align}$$

Comment: As written your integral should be with respect to $k$, not $x$.  So the anti-derivative is $\tan^{-1}(kx) / x$, not $\tan^{-1}(kx) / k$.

Comment: Michael Joyce thanks! you are right

Comment: I made some formatting changes to your post. Take a look to see how I did it. I note that you use far more braces `{}` than you need to in your typesetting. Even I used more than are strictly needed, here--for example, `$(kx)^2$` and `$(kx)^{2}$` both give $(kx)^2,$ but for multi-character superscripts, we *do* need the braces, so I didn't want to mislead you. Also, that `$\limits$` thing is a lot less cumbersome than nesting undersets and oversets. Hope it all looks okay to you.

Comment: Thanks for your advises:) But i'm using a converter. so they come automatically. i do not write manually. but i will take notice of the format.